# How to grant domain wide privs to your service account during app installation

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, service-accounts

I have a Google Marketplace app that uses a service account for access user's drive account. It requires domain wide grants,

As per the doc here: 
https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/delegation

"""
If the service account is listed as an app on the Google Apps Marketplace, then domain-wide access to user data is granted during the installation of that app.
"""

However I cannot find a way to specify the service account id in my app, how do I make sure that the service account is indeed granted privileges when the admin installs the app

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use service account when authenticating & authorizing your app to access Drive API.

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/service-accounts explains the process pretty well along with a sample.